# Google maps API v3 MarkerCluster not performing cluster

Tags: google-maps

I am in he middle of writing a custom map using the Google Map v3 API for a custom website for a project.

Currently I have a bunch of markers scattered around, and as there is over 100 of them I would preferably like to place them in a MarkerCluster, however when looking through the many tutorials and already asked questions, I have managed to get myself a point now where either all my markers disappear or only 1 is displayed and when zooming the others do not appear.

This is my first time working with the Google API so everything is fairly new to me, any help at all is really appreciated!.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDINxXHHp6_arevhHdyZZ5W3ty0mEWjzd4&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //declare map and map type (zoom level and where to centre the map on loading)
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    draggable: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.403938,-2.987954),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                mapOptions);


   var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 25};
  setMarkers(map, wifimaplocation);


}


var wifimaplocation = [
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub', 53.410133,-2.980967, 4],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 2', 53.410581,-2.98513, 5],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 3', 53.410341,-2.986254, 3],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 6ER)', 53.408816,-2.983669, 2],
  ['Yates Bros Wine Lodge', 53.407319,-2.98397, 1],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 4', 53.408373,-2.982217, 6],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 5', 53.408926,-2.983751, 7],
  ['Liverpool Marriot Hotel',53.408926,-2.983751, 8],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 1 St Johns Lane', 53.408563,-2.982344, 9],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 1 Roe St)', 53.407407,-2.981337, 10],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 6', 53.40701,-2.981944, 11],
  ['McDonald&#39s St Johns Precinct', 53.407121,-2.980573, 12],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 7', 53.406705,-2.980839, 13],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 8', 53.406859,-2.980066, 14],
  ['Network Rail - Liverpool Lime Street', 53.408688,-2.9788, 15],
  ['Wetherspoons', 53.405942,-2.979522, 16],
  ['Crown', 53.406484,-2.978754, 17],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 9', 53.406574,-2.978513, 18],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 10', 53.406574,-2.978513, 19],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 11', 53.406488,-2.978749, 20],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L3 5 Bolton St)', 53.405898,-2.97773, 21],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 12', 53.408026,-2.977398, 22],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Skelhorne St)', 53.416157,-2.988889, 23],
  ['McDonald&#39s (Ranelagh Street)', 53.404594,-2.977877, 24],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Renshaw St)', 53.404639,-2.977296, 25],
  ['Wetherspoons', 53.405183,-2.980989, 26],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 13', 53.405339,-2.979956, 27],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 14', 53.404869,-2.97993, 28],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 15', 53.403862,-2.979275, 29],
  ['Brew Tea Bar', 53.403862,-2.979275, 30],
  ['Starbucks Coffee', 53.404054,-2.980643, 31],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 16', 53.404054,-2.980643, 32],
  ['Office (Holmes Building Wood Street)', 53.404223,-2.981673, 33],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 17', 53.403512,-2.980543, 34],
  ['Djandos-Riff', 53.403512,-2.980543, 35],
  ['Bar Liverpool Ltd', 53.403512,-2.980543, 36],
  ['O Neills', 53.404174,-2.981809, 37],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 18', 53.405538,-2.98094, 38],
  ['Currys/PC World', 53.404789,-2.982451, 39],
  ['BT Pay Phone (Church Street)', 53.405506,-2.982687, 40],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 19', 53.406759,-2.98384, 41],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 20', 53.406686,-2.984221, 42],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 21', 53.406775,-2.98454, 43],
  ['Cafe Nero', 53.407034,-2.98483, 44],
  ['Ice', 53.406795,-2.98491, 45],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 22', 53.406142,-2.984355, 46],
  ['WiFi Pod Office', 53.402954,-2.984422, 47],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 23', 53.403424,-2.984184, 48],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 24', 53.404203,-2.984097, 49],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 25', 53.404697,-2.985109, 50],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 26', 53.403798,-2.985541, 51],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 27',53.406863,-2.98583, 52],
  ['McDonalds', 53.405218,-2.986485, 53],
  ['WELKIN (Wetherspoons)', 53.405998,-2.985895, 54],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 28', 53.405237,-2.98648, 55],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 29', 53.405741,-2.986495, 56],
  ['1Pco Lord Street Liverpool', 53.405183,-2.98649, 57],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 30', 53.405132,-2.987064, 58],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 31', 53.403868,-2.987311, 59],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 32', 53.403894,-2.98648, 60],
  ['Liverpool Moat House', 53.401345,-2.985981, 61],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Paradise Street)', 53.401345,-2.985981, 62],
  ['Starbucks 2', 53.402583,-2.986039, 63],
  ['John Lewis', 53.402963,-2.986796, 64],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 33', 53.402986,-2.98442, 65],
  ['Cafe Nero', 53.404462,-2.984958, 66],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 34', 53.406296,-2.99516, 67],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 35', 53.404654,-2.991283, 68],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (James Street)', 53.404654,-2.991283, 69],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 36', 53.405285,-2.99319, 70],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 37', 53.405608,-2.99139, 71],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 38', 53.405682,-2.991801, 72],
  ['Brunswick Street', 53.40619,-2.992869, 73],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Brunswick Street)', 53.40619,-2.992869, 74],
  ['Heywood House Hotel', 53.406695,-2.988615, 75],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 39', 53.406657,-2.990288, 76],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 40', 53.408013,-2.988277, 77],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 41', 53.408262,-2.98766, 78],
  ['Premier Inn - Liverpool City Centre', 53.409174,-2.988051, 79],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 42', 53.409295,-2.987504, 80],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 43', 53.409577,-2.988051, 81],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 44', 53.409922,-2.987174, 82],
  ['Liverpool - Hatton Garden / Tithebarn Street', 53.410632,-2.987276, 83],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 45', 53.410302,-2.98627, 84],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage - Liverpool (Hatton Garden)', 53.410302,-2.98627, 85],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 46', 53.410993,-2.986823, 86],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 47', 53.410542,-2.985216, 87],
  ['Brunswick Vaults', 53.410376,-2.989443, 88],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 48', 53.410168,-2.98884, 89],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 49', 53.410389,-2.989615, 90],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 50', 53.408943,-2.990245, 91],
  ['Railway', 53.408969,-2.990422, 92],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 51', 53.408787,-2.991678, 93],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 52', 53.408774,-2.994178, 94],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 53', 53.405682,-2.978199, 95],
  ['Brew Tea Bar', 53.410159,-2.993776, 96],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 54', 53.410159,-2.993776, 97],
  ['Cross Keys Public House', 53.409916,-2.993743, 98],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 55', 53.404812,-2.977298, 99],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 56', 53.404313,-2.976676, 100],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 57', 53.404697,-2.976611, 101],
  ['stayCity Liverpool Mount Pleasant', 53.405183,-2.976314, 102],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 58', 53.405132,-2.976547, 103],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 59', 53.404275,-2.973522, 104],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 60', 53.404646,-2.972556, 105],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 61', 53.404518,-2.972341, 106],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 62', 53.404607,-2.971161, 107],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Brownlow Hill)', 53.403878,-2.97129, 108],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 63', 53.40526,-2.967471, 109],
  ['Starbucks', 53.41154,-2.965196, 110],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 64', 53.410888,-2.967041, 111],
  ['Liverpool - London Road', 53.409455,-2.97659, 112],
  ['BT Openzone Business Hub 65', 53.41012,-2.969573, 113],
  ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Pembroke Place)', 53.409238,-2.971505, 114]




];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('image.png',
  //     // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
       new google.maps.Size(40, 35),
  //     // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  //     // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
       new google.maps.Point(0, 0));
   var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('shadow.png',
  //     // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
  //     // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
       new google.maps.Size(62, 35),
       new google.maps.Point(0,0),
       new google.maps.Point(0, 0));
  //     // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
  //     // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
  //     // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
  //     // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
  //     // coordinate.
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };



  for (var i = 0; i < wifimaplocation.length; i++) {
    var wifi = wifimaplocation[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(wifi[1], wifi[2], wifi[3]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: wifi[0],
        zIndex: wifi[3]

    });

    markers.push(wifimaplocation);


   var mc = new MarkerCluster(map, mcOptions, wifimaplocation);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(wifimaplocation[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));


}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong arguments to the MarkerClusterer constructor and you misspelled MarkerClusterer (note the extra 'er'). Needs to be like this:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,markers,mcOptions);
```

Also, don't assign the map value in your new Marker construcor if you are going to pass it to the clusterer.

[working fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919606/google-maps-markerclusters-not-working-for-some-locations)

You need to push *[google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)* objects into the markers array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didnt even notice I had missed off the extra "er", however when changing the constructor to what you suggested:

`var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,markers,mcOptions);`

It removes all but one of my markers, the first one in the array is the only one shown on the map

Comment: See my edits. Also, play with your options. MaxZoom 25 seems way too high.

Comment: so change the:

 `setMarkers(map, wifimaplocation);`

to

 `setMarkers(wifimaplocation);` ?