# Google Maps MarkerClusters not working for some locations

Tags: google-maps

I have a large number of locations/markers, so I'm using MarkerClusters. This is working great except for the one cluster. The cluster shows that there are 3 locations but if you click on it, it doesn't show any locations. I cannot seem to find a starting point to debug this issue since I don't see any errors or warnings. Has anyone run into this before or have any advice?

Example: Click the cluster with 3 locations near Honolulu to see what I mean. [link](http://findyourplace.herokuapp.com/#/universities)

I'm using the Angular Google Maps directive ([github](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps))

Gist to my code: https://gist.github.com/fourq/bb30d2335ec2ab40170a

Comment: That is not the only one, similar for Tucson. Do you maybe have some markers without map set?

Comment: @AntoJurković hmm. well if you search for "hawaii" in the search box those locations show up and show on the map. I will however check the database for to locations that are being fed to the map. Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not just a link to your web page.

Comment: How are you configuring the MarkerClusterer?

Comment: @geocodezip I've edited the question with a gist to my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/448

and play with gridSize as stated in here.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.1/docs/reference.html#MarkerClustererOptions

My guess the data is way too close together or you have dupes.

Comment: thank you. I think the issue is duplicate addresses since the ministries are all at the same location.